# How to use Aria encryption algorithm in Bouncy Castle and C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, block-cipher

According to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptography_libraries) and [this](https://www.bouncycastle.org/releasenotes.html) page, Bouncy Castle library contains the implementation of [Aria Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARIA_(cipher)) algorithm. but I could not find any documentation for how to use this algorithm in C# and the library?

could someone please help me and describe how to use the library to implement the algorithm?

thank you in advance

Comment: It is *not* supported in the C# library, only in the Java library.

Comment: Should be easy to convert this kind of code to Java though; the languages are really rather similar and there are not too many dependencies. The only issue is that the number format is somewhat different (unsigned vs signed integers, big enian vs runtime specific endianness).

Comment: I meant "from Java" of course, not "to Java". Guessing from the upvotes, that was clear.